# ROWLOCK in Stored Procedure with Composite Key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

**EDITED:** I have a table with composite key which is being used by multiple windows services deployed on multiple servers.

Columns:

```
UserId (int) [CompositeKey],
CheckinTimestamp (bigint) [CompositeKey],
Status (tinyint)
```

There will be continuous insertion in this table. I want my windows service to select top 10000 rows and do some processing while locking those 10000 rows only. I am using ROWLOCK for this using below stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE LockMonitoringSession
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    SELECT TOP 10000 * INTO #TempMonitoringSession FROM dbo.MonitoringSession WITH (ROWLOCK) WHERE [Status] = 0 ORDER BY UserId

    DECLARE @UserId INT
    DECLARE @CheckinTimestamp BIGINT

    DECLARE SessionCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT UserId, CheckinTimestamp FROM #TempMonitoringSession

    OPEN SessionCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM SessionCursor INTO @UserId, @CheckinTimestamp

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.MonitoringSession SET [Status] = 1 WHERE UserId = @UserId AND CheckinTimestamp = @CheckinTimestamp
        FETCH NEXT FROM SessionCursor INTO @UserId, @CheckinTimestamp
    END

    CLOSE SessionCursor
    DEALLOCATE SessionCursor

    SELECT * FROM #TempMonitoringSession
    DROP TABLE #TempMonitoringSession

    COMMIT TRANSACTION  
END
```

But by doing so, `dbo.MonitoringSession` is being locked permanently until the stored procedure ends. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

**The only purpose of this stored procedure is to select and update 10000 recent rows without any primary key and ensuring that whole table is not locked because multiple windows services are accessing this table.**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No `order by` for `top`, no `where` in `update` - this is only in simplified code posted with question? Can you post actual execution plan for select-top?

Comment: If you are just updating 10 rows why do you need a loop at all? This could be done in a single statement.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement has no `WHERE` clause, so this `UPDATE` operation is applied *against the WHOLE table*, so each row in the table will be **exclusively locked** to perform the `UPDATE` .....

Comment: Further to what marc said,you are performing the same op 50 K times

Comment: Guys, I have edited the question and posted original code. I also rephrased the question and mentioned the purpose of this SP. Please have a look now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*(not an answer but too long for comment)*

The purpose description should be about why/what for are you updating whole table. Your SP is for updating all rows with `Status=0` to set `Status=1`. So when one of your services decides to run this SP - all rows become non-relevant. I mean, logically event which causes status change already occurred, you just need some time to physically change it in the database. So why do you want other services to read non-relevant rows? Ok, probably you need to read rows available to read (not changed) - but it's not clear again because you are updating *whole* table.

You may use `READPAST` hint to skip locked rows and you need rowlocks for that.
Ok, but even with processing of top N rows update of those N rows with one statement would be much faster then looping through this number of rows. You are doing same job but manually.

Check out example of combining `UPDLOCK` + `READPAST` to process same queue with parallel processes: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1257/processing-data-queues-in-sql-server-with-readpast-and-updlock/

Small hint - `CURSOR STATIC, READONLY, FORWARD_ONLY` would do same thing as storing to temp table. Review `STATIC` option:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Another thing is a suggestion to think of [RCSI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095(v=sql.105).aspx). This will avoid other services locking for sure but this is a db-level option so you'll have to test all your functionality. Most of it will work same as before but some scenarios need testing (concurrent transactions won't be locked in situations where they were locked before).

Not clear to me:

- what is the percentage of 10000 out of the total number of rows?
- is there a clustered index or this is a heap?
- what is actual execution plan for select and update?
- what are concurrent transactions: inserts or selects?

by the way discovered similar question:
[why the entire table is locked while "with (rowlock)" is used in an update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042739/why-the-entire-table-is-locked-while-with-rowlock-is-used-in-an-update-state)

Comment: Thank you @Ivan for the detailed reply. When my services run for the first time, there will be a total of 100,000 rows in that table already. There will be continuous insertions occurring in this table (approx. 500 rows per second). As you can see, I have selected all the data before dropping that temp table. When data is returned to the service, it will take around 4-5 minutes to do some processing for that data. There's clustered index on UserId, CheckinTimestamp. I want my service to pick maximum number of rows and update those right away and return those rows to the service again.

Comment: I don't want to lock my whole table as there are 10 instances of services continuously hitting that table. And also there is an ongoing insertion on that table also. I faced the problem before implementing lock, when 2 or more services queried that table at once and picked same rows for execution. Estimated number of total rows in the table could be in millions.

Comment: I was also wondering that, is there any way to SELECT and UPDATE in a same query using composite key. Almost in every solution on internet, I found that developers used to select the primary key column in a temp table. Then update and select from that table for the selected primary keys in temp table. I was unable to find solution with composite key.

Comment: Add surrogate ID key to your table and make it clustered index. Right now inserts running may require pages in the middle of clustered index to be locked and sometimes split. And post actual execution plans for select and update (asked twice already). For concurrent readers - review what column they filter by, do they need all columns of this table. May be it'll make sense to build additional non-clustered index for readers. What is percentage of rows with Status=0?